# UISegmentedControl selected index always 0?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, interface-builder, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a UISegmentedControl that has 6 segments which I created in Interface Builder. I am calling the following method on value changed:

```
-(IBAction)segmentedChartButtonChanged:(id)sender
{
    switch (self.segmentedChartButton.selectedSegmentIndex) {
        case 0:
            NSLog(@"5d selected. Index: %d", self.segmentedChartButton.selectedSegmentIndex);
            break;
        case 1:
            NSLog(@"3m selected. Index: %d", self.segmentedChartButton.selectedSegmentIndex);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Whenever I change the segments, the `selectedSegmentIndex is always 0`. Why is this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It is very likely that the `IBOutlet` isn't connected. Check that. You can also use the `sender` that is passed to the method.

```
UISegmentedControl * segmentedControl = (UISegmentedControl *)sender;
switch (segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex) {
    ....
```

Comment: check the Main.storyboard object if connected to .h @property. Cheers

Answer (score 4):

hi try like this it will work

```
-(IBAction)segmentedChartButtonChanged:(id)sender
 {
 UISegmentedControl *segment=(UISegmentedControl*)sender;
switch (segment.selectedSegmentIndex) {
    case 0:
        NSLog(@"5d selected. Index: %d", self.segmentedChartButton.selectedSegmentIndex);
        break;
    case 1:
        NSLog(@"3m selected. Index: %d", self.segmentedChartButton.selectedSegmentIndex);
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Take an outlet for UISegmentedControl and handle with that like this,

```
if (self.paymentSegmentButton.selectedSegmentIndex ==0)
{
    NSLog(@"first view ");

}
else
{
    NSLog(@"payment initiation");
    addVC = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil]instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"secondView"];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:addVC animated:YES];

       }
```

I hope it helps someone.