# Iterating through UISegmentedControl values

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisegmentedcontrol

I've created a UISegmentedControl in IB and added four segments for it. What I want to do now is restoring the selection of the control from a value stored in my data model.

Is it possible to iterate through the segments of the UISegmentedControl and set the selectedSegmentIndex of a specific index?

My action handler for the UISegmentControl looks like this:

```
-(IBAction)onAmountSelectorChange:(id)sender
{
    NSString *s = [amountSelector titleForSegmentAtIndex:[amountSelector selectedSegmentIndex]];
    int v = s.intValue;
    _nameGenParams.amount = v;
}
```

... now I need to reverse the action so the right index is restored from _nameGenParams.amount.

**UPDATE**: Trying to store the index to NSUserDefaults by using:

```
    NSInteger i = amountSelector.selectedSegmentIndex;
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:i forKey:@"amountSelectorSegIndex"];
```

But this doesn't seem to work. I execute this in my action handler and restore it in viewDidLoad with:

```
NSUInteger amountSelectorSegIndex = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"amountSelectorSegIndex"];
amountSelector.selectedSegmentIndex = amountSelectorSegIndex;
```

The UISegmentedControl doesn't set to my stored index What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE 2:** I've defined the UISegmentControl as an IBOutlet in my interface as:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *amountSelector;
```

And in my controller class I synthesize it:

```
@synthesize amountSelector;
```

Can anyone tell me why setting/getting a value to amountSelector isn't working here (it also is still 0 after I restore the index with:

```
    amountSelector.selectedSegmentIndex = amountSelectorSegIndex;
```

Comment: You have to call `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];` to persist data to the disk after you use `setInteger:forKey:` (see documentation on `synchronize` method for performance considerations)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually `selectedSegmentIndex` is a writable property on `UISegmentedControl`

When need to restore you want to do something similar to

```
NSUInteger preservedSegmentedIndex = [[NSUserDefaults  standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"preservedSegmentedIndex"];
segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = preservedSegmentedIndex;
```

Comment: OK, as far as I understand, this method is to restore from a local UI state storage (NSUserDefaults)? Then how do I store the state (seg index) to NSUserDefaults in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

```
NSInteger i = amountSelector.selectedSegmentIndex;
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:i forKey:@"amountSelectorSegIndex"];
```

is also correct, but see weather i is having the correct value or not.

Comment: Actually it seems my value is not correct. If I put   NSLog(@"%ld", (long)amountSelector.selectedSegmentIndex);
into my action handler it turns out it is 0 after every selection change.

Comment: OK, if I follow this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6585896/uisegmentedcontrol-selected-index-always-0 it works! For some reason it doesn't work if I synthesize my amountSelector and use that in my action handler to get the index.

Comment: Alright! Nevermind! For some reason the connection to the outlet definition was broken. Reconnecting this again made it work!

Comment: @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *amountSelector;  

with ARC, the property for Outlet should be weak, so use weak instead of strong

Comment: Ok thanks! I'm not very familiar with the strong/weak clause. Then in which situations is it recommended to use strong properties (with ARC)?

Comment: you can use strong to all other properties but not for the IBOutlet connections. Outlet connections should be always weak. so you shouldn't have to nil them out in viewDidUnload.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the tip keshav!